# Block bots accessing wp-login.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, bots, blocking

I've launched my first real website last week and after analyzing the logs, I found that some bots are searching for vulnerabilities in the website.

For example, somes are calling ajax web pages without being on the website. Others are trying to access to the wp-login.php page even if the website is not powered by Wordpress. Actually, the first ones have been able to produce an error on the website which is why I've looked threw the logs.

I came to an idea of a script which everytime an IP hits the wp-login.php page, I add it to the .htaccess file to block the IP.

Is it a great solution to fight against these bots ? 
What would you do ?

Comment: http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Answer (score 1):

*Is* your website powered by wordpress or not?

If it is not, and they are just getting "404 not found" for the file, then i would not worry to much about it yet as most will just move on after seeing these files do not exist. There are literally millions and millions of rogue bots on the web probing for these common file paths.

What you need to learn is .HTaccess and PHP. (if your server has these things.)

You definitely do not want to add just single IP addresses into your .HTaccess file. This should be reserved for large block ranges of IP addresses, most of which should be data center block IP's, and not ISP blocks.

There is no simple answer to blocking bots as there is a different solution for the many scenarios in different environments.

Bottom line here is if you yourself want to do the blocking, it will require you to learn actual server side scripting languages, and other server security measures. Also you could use Javascript for certain filters as well.

If you are on Apache server - learn some .HTaccess and PHP. Those 2 are invaluable to you. They will give you GOD status over your environment.